# Element width displayed incorrectly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is that my `header` has a fixed width of 150px, but in browser it gets displayed as 134.984px and I can't figure out why. I've tried everthing that I could think of but nothing worked. The only thing I've managed to figure out is that it's the `content-wrap` flex item that is pushing on the `header`and making it smaller.

Here's the HTML:

```css
/*======= Container =======*/

#container{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
 width: 100%;
}
/*======= Sāna izvēlne / header =======*/

header {
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 150px;
 margin: 0;
}

.header-position {
 width: inherit;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

nav li, a {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: right;

 font-size: 1em;
 color: black;

}



.logo {

 background: url("../images/AG.svg");
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 80px;
}

/*======= Banneris =======*/

.banner-container {
 background-image: url("../images/lp-background.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 clear: right;
}

.banner {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
}
.banner h1 {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 0.4em;
 border: solid 10px white;
 padding: 20px 30px;
}

/*======= Par mums =======*/

#about {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: pink;
}

#about .first, .second {
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

#about .first {

}
#about .second {
 float: right;
}

.about-picture {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 margin: 50px 50px;
 border-radius: 150px;
 border: solid 4px rgb(246, 243, 199);
}
.about-picture.right {
 float: right;
}
img.right {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <header>
  <div class="header-position">
   <img class="logo" src="./images/AG.svg" alt="AG Logo"></img>

   <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sākums</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Attēli</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Kontakti</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Par mums</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   <a href="mailto:">Sazinies ar mums</a>
  </div>
 </header>

 <div id="content-wrap">

   <div class="banner-container">

    <span class="banner"><h1>Whatever</h1></span>

   </div>

   <div id="about">
    <div class="first">
     <img class="about-picture left" src="./images/lp-background.jpg" alt="" />

    </div>
    <div class="second">
     <img class="about-picture right" src="./images/lp-background.jpg" alt="" />

    </div>
   </div>

 </div>
```

How do I get the 'header' to be displayed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's a flex-item you need to set it's flex properties accordingly.

```
header {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: red;
    flex: 0 0 150px; /* don't grow, don't shrink, be 150px wide */
  }
```

```css
/*======= Container =======*/

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#content-wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
/*======= Sāna izvēlne / header =======*/

header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
.header-position {
  width: inherit;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
}
.logo {
  background: url("../images/AG.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 80px;
}
/*======= Banneris =======*/

.banner-container {
  background-image: url("../images/lp-background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  clear: right;
}
.banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.banner h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.4em;
  border: solid 10px white;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
/*======= Par mums =======*/

#about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#about .first,
.second {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#about .first {} #about .second {
  float: right;
}
.about-picture {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  border: solid 4px rgb(246, 243, 199);
}
.about-picture.right {
  float: right;
}
img.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <div class="header-position">
      <img class="logo" src="./images/AG.svg" alt="AG Logo"></img>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sākums</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Attēli</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Kontakti</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Par mums</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="mailto:">Sazinies ar mums</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="content-wrap">

    <div class="banner-container">

      <span class="banner"><h1>Whatever</h1></span>

    </div>

    <div id="about">
      <div class="first">
        <img class="about-picture left" src="./images/lp-background.jpg" alt="" />

      </div>
      <div class="second">
        <img class="about-picture right" src="./images/lp-background.jpg" alt="" />

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```